# MongoDB & Partial indexes : Avoid filtering stage when filtering on null date

Tags: mongodb, indexing, compound-index, partial-index

I am trying to optimize a DB lookup as best as I can. From what I understand, my goal should be to target a winningPlan where the only stage is an IXScan. But I have a field containing date keys, and it seems like I cannot build a compound index that will be able to lookup directly documents when filtering on "null" date values.

My filter query is the following

```
    {"$and":[
      {"published":true},
      {"soft_deleted_at":null}, # <-- this one's a date field, I need null values
      {"another_filter":false},
      {"yet_another_filter":false}
    ]}`
```

I tried building a partial index that would correspond exactly to this query (in order to also save up some index memory, since I know I will never have to show documents that are soft deleted for example)

(Note that the code is in Ruby, but it translates to MongoDB language without any problem using Mongoid)

```rb
index(
  {
    published: 1,
    another_filter: 1,
    soft_deleted_at: 1,
    yet_another_filter: 1,
  },
  {
    background: true,
    name: 'Visible in search engine partial index',
    partial_filter_expression: {
      '$and': [
        {"published":true},
        {"soft_deleted_at":null},
        {"another_filter":false},
        {"yet_another_filter":false}
      ]
    }
  }
)
```

This seems to work well except for the `soft_deleted_at` filter, since my winning plan looks like

```rb
=> {"stage"=>"FETCH",
 "filter"=>{"soft_deleted_at"=>{"$eq"=>nil}},
 "inputStage"=>
  {"stage"=>"IXSCAN",
   "keyPattern"=>{"published"=>1, "another_filter"=>1, "soft_deleted_at"=>1, "yet_another_filter"=>1},
   "indexName"=>"Visible in search engine partial index",
   "isMultiKey"=>false,
   "multiKeyPaths"=>{"published"=>[], "another_filter"=>[], "soft_deleted_at"=>[], "yet_another_filter"=>[]},
   "isUnique"=>false,
   "isSparse"=>false,
   "isPartial"=>true,
   "indexVersion"=>2,
   "direction"=>"forward",
   "indexBounds"=>
    {"published"=>["[true, true]"], "another_filter"=>["[false, false]"], "soft_deleted_at"=>["[null, null]"], "yet_another_filter"=>["[false, false]"]}}}
```

So here I have this extra stage `"stage"=>"FETCH", "filter"=>{"soft_deleted_at"=>{"$eq"=>nil}},` which is basically manually filtering my date field fr null values. I was hoping this would already be in the partial index and not require more filtering... was I wrong ?

Is there some way I can avoid this extra filter stage ?

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some way I can avoid this extra filter stage ?

No, there's not. (At least, not with your current data schema)

Mongo creates indexes for non-existence (null & undefined) a bit differently than existence. It is actually using the `soft_deleted_at` index (note that it's filtering on a range of `[null, null]`, but that's also fetching values where `soft_deleted_at` is `undefined`. It isn't able to use the index to filter out those values, so it has to do that `filter` step.

While in general, it's best to avoid filter stages, this doesn't seem like a case where it's going to be costly. You won't be fetching any extra documents, so the only cost is inspecting the fetched documents for a single field.

The alternative would be to add a value like `false` and search by that. If you had a field like `deleted` that was either true or false for every documents (and that you updated at the same time as `soft_deleted_at`) your query plan wouldn't include a `filter` stage.